# Fluent Bit cannot reach DNS for Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure-aks, fluent-bit

I'm running Fluent Bit on Azure Kubernetes Service as DaemonSet, output goes to Azure Log Analytics. Once Fluent Bit tries to send logs it fails to connect DNS server:

`getaddrinfo(host='XXX.ods.opinsights.azure.com', err=12): Timeout while contacting DNS servers`

If I manually enter IP and `XXX.ods.opinsights.azure.com` into `/etc/hosts`, everything goes well.

If I ssh to fluent-bit pod and run `wget XXX.ods.opinsights.azure.com` host resolving works as well.

What can be wrong?

**My configs:**

**ConfigMap**

```
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: fluent-bit-config
      namespace: airflow
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluent-bit
    data:
      fluent-bit.conf: |
        [SERVICE]
            Flush         1
            Log_Level     info
            Daemon        off
            HTTP_Server   On
            HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
            HTTP_Port     2020
        @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
        @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
        @INCLUDE output-azure.conf
      input-kubernetes.conf: |
        [INPUT]
            Name              tail
            Tag               kube.*
            Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
            DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
            Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
            Skip_Long_Lines   On
            Refresh_Interval  10
      filter-kubernetes.conf: |
        [FILTER]
            Name                kubernetes
            Match               kube.*
            Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
            Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
            Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
            Merge_Log           On
            K8S-Logging.Parser  Off
            K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
      output-azure.conf: |
        [OUTPUT]
            Name        azure
            Match       *
            Customer_ID xxx
            Shared_Key  yyy
```

**DaemonSet**

```
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: DaemonSet
    metadata:
      name: fluentbit
      namespace: airflow
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: fluentbit
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          name: fluentbit
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            name: fluentbit
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: fluent-bit
          containers:
            - name: fluent-bit
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              image: fluent/fluent-bit:1.8-debug
              volumeMounts:
              - name: varlog
                mountPath: /var/log
              - name: varlibdockercontainers
                mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
                readOnly: true
              - name: fluent-bit-config
                mountPath: /fluent-bit/etc/
              resources:
                limits:
                  memory: 1500Mi
                requests:
                  cpu: 500m
                  memory: 500Mi
          hostNetwork: true
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
          volumes:
          - name: varlog
            hostPath:
              path: /var/log
          - name: varlibdockercontainers
            hostPath:
              path: /var/lib/docker/containers
          - name: fluent-bit-config
            configMap:
              name: fluent-bit-config
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran against a similar issue today, downgrading the version of fluent bit to 1.8.4 resolved the issue. (https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/4050)

In your case you would need to fix the docker container label to "1.8.4-debug" - hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm findings above. same result with 1.8.5. had to go back to 1.8.4.